# Java program stop work

Tags: java, jvm

```
try {
            final Connection connection =
                    DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);



            final AtomicInteger start = new AtomicInteger(0);
            final AtomicInteger preFix = new AtomicInteger(201401);
            final int perCount = 1000;
            ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
            service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    String sql = "select id,class,function,remark,add_time from ";
                    sql += "table_";
                    sql += preFix.get();
                    sql += " order by id limit ";
                    sql += start.get();
                    sql += ",";
                    sql += perCount;
                    ResultSet resultSet = null;
                    List<Email> emailList = new ArrayList<Email>();
                    try{
                        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                        while (resultSet.next()){
                            Email email = new Email();
                            long  id = resultSet.getLong("id");
                            email.setId(id + "");
                            String userEmail = resultSet.getString("class");
                            email.setUserEmail(userEmail);
                            String subject = resultSet.getString("function");
                            email.setSubject(subject);
                            String content = resultSet.getString("remark");
                            email.setContent(content);
                            long addTime = resultSet.getLong("add_time");
                            email.setAddDate(addTime);
                            emailList.add(email);
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }




//                    List<Email> emailList = emailDao.getEmailList(start.get(),perCount);

                    List<Order> studentList = new ArrayList<Order>();
                    if(null != emailList && emailList.size() > 0){
                        System.out.println("emailList size:" + emailList.size());
                        for(Email email:emailList){
                            if(email.getSend() == 1){
                                Order order = new Order();
                                order.setOrderId(Integer.valueOf(email.getId()));
                                String content = new String(email.getContent());
                                order.setOrderSign(content + "verygood");
                                studentList.add(order);
                            }
                        }
                        start.set(start.get() + perCount);
                    }else{//another table

                        int n = preFix.getAndIncrement();
                        System.out.println("useing table:" + n);
                        if(n == 201412){
                            preFix.set(201401);
                        }
                        start.set(0);
                    }

                    if(null != studentList){
                        studentList.clear();
                        studentList = null;
                    }
                }
            },0,200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

above is my program,when use jvm_option "-server  -Xmx50m -Xms50m" the program work well,but when reduce the memory like this "-server  -Xmx10m -Xms10m" ,after a seconds program stoped work,and jvm is not doing gc.
use command:jstat -gcutil 4116 2s
result is:
![enter image description here][1]

```
  S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT

 0.00   0.00  12.72  34.90  55.08     36    0.117    36    0.666    0.783

 0.00   0.00  12.72  34.90  55.08     36    0.117    36    0.666    0.783

 0.00   0.00  12.72  34.90  55.08     36    0.117    36    0.666    0.783
```

i want know why

Comment: We're not compilers. You'll have to tell us what the error is and where it's located. Minimizing your code to what's relevant would be nice too.

Comment: Has any attempt been made at debugging this? It should be relatively straight forwards to step through the code in Eclipse or Netbeans and monitoring the JVM memory usage using JVisualVM to see what is happening with the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10mb is a very small amount of memory, and before I go any further I want to make it clear that **it is not enough memory**.  The permanent space is taking up 55.08% of that amount.  Old generation is taking up 34.90%, and the Eden space is at 12.72%.  This adds up to **102.7% of the maximum heap size you've allowed**, and I'm guessing that an OutOfMemoryError was thrown shortly after this reading.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html#gcutil_option

Comment: thanks for Floegipoky's answer.After old generation is full, jvm is doing full  gc frequently,and the program stopd.Reason why jvm is always doing full gc is that:preparedStatement is not closed,so it can't be gc,finally the memory is use up.